# Using sed throws No such file or directory

Tags: sed

I am very new to shell script and trying to learn it.

My use case with Shell script is that I need to replace a particular string with an empty string on all the files content which are inside a folder. The following is my folder structure.

```
-> RootFolder
   -> applications
       -> a.app
   -> layout
       -> Account-Service Plus Account Layout.layout
       -> Address-Service Plus Address Layout.layout
   -> classes
       -> A.cls
       -> B.cls
```

I am getting below error on files which has the name with spaces. Can anyone point me what I have missed over there?

```
../RootFolder/layouts/Account-Service
sed: can't read ../RootFolder/layouts/Account-Service: No such file or directory
Plus
sed: can't read Plus: No such file or directory
Account
sed: can't read Account: No such file or directory
Layout.layout
```

My script is,

```
for d in $(find ../RootFolder -maxdepth 2 -type f)
do
  echo "$d"
  sed -i "s/test/''/g" "$d"
done
```

Comment: I think space in filename is causing the issue. You shouldn't be using `for+find` like this, use `-exec` option instead. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice

Comment: And do yourself a favor, if you can: do not put spaces (tabs, newlines, special characters) in your file or directory names. It very frequently (and uselessly) complicate things. Some super-useful tools even become almost unusable because they are not designed with such names in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have spaces in your file names (which is not a very good idea if you want to automate your processing) you must code everything with this in mind.

```
for d in $(find ../RootFolder -maxdepth 2 -type f)
```

will treat each space-separated word independently, even if they are parts of the same file name. A more robust solution consists in using the `-print0` option of `find`, that uses the null character as output separator, and write your loop such that it also uses the null character as the separator:

```
find ../RootFolder -maxdepth 2 -type f -print0 | \
while IFS= read -r -d '' d; do
  echo "$d"
  sed -i "s/test/''/g" "$d"
done
```

The `read` command is used with:

- `IFS=` (empty Input Field Separator) to preserve leading and trailing spaces,
- the `-r` option to preserve backslashes and
- the `-d ''` option to use the null character as the word separator.

With this, `find` can output any crazy file names, they should be passed to the `while` loop in the `d` shell variable, unmodified and one at a time... Unless your file system allows null characters in file names (I don't know any such file system but I don't know them all).

Comment: I am getting source-deployment.sh: line 45: warning: here-document at line 41 delimited by end-of-file (wanted ``(find ../$outputfolder -maxdepth 2 
-type f -print0)`') warning.

Comment: Are you using bash? If yes you probably forgot a space between the two `<` of the last line. Try maybe to copy-paste instead of writing by hand. If you are not using bash, pipe the `find` command to `while` instead of using redirection and process substitution: `find ... | while ...` See the edited answer in which I removed this bash-ism.